# .net Comment System

Tags: .net, system, comments

I have my web site with a blog (created in blogengine), but i need to integrate a comment system to the site away from the blog.

for example i have different modules to manage news and events and i want visitors to leave their comments for the modules (for difreent news and events). Is there any system (.net 2.0) to do this or i need to create my own system to manage users comments?

thx a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of comment management modules you can get your hands on. Some are open source, some are closed. Some are drop-in, and some require extensive configuration (but generally better integration).

Personally, I prefer the drop-in solution of the PageComments user control in [this package](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/837/ItemPermalink.ashx).

A good starting point for this would be to take a look at the Control Gallery on [asp.net](http://www.asp.net) for commenting systems: [Control Gallery: "comments"](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/search.aspx?search=1&text=comment&SortByField=ItemDownloads%20desc)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of CMS-/portal-type applications, which offer the required functionality (e.g. [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/)). But I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.